# Is it possible to get emails after specific message id

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I have implemented IMAP Idle client using this example.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/ImapIdleExample.cs

I have millions of emails. I am saving message ids of emails as I am reading them.

In an event where computer/server hosting code is shutdown or restarted.

Is it possible to start reading emails after specific message id.

I do not want re fetch all emails which are already read by code.

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? In sequential order?

Comment: yes, in sequential order.

Comment: Likely If the use case is a retart and we talk of millions of emails, you may want some roder based (order incoming into the server) paging to not download iat all over and over again.

Comment: I am thinking of moving all read emails to specific folder. I think that can be considered a viable strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the `MimeMessage.MessageId`, why not just save which `UniqueId`'s your program has seen? They don't change between session and they are sequentially ordered.

This is how every IMAP mail client in the world avoids re-downloading the same messages over and over.

Comment: I am saving unique ids. How do I skip emails by unqiue ids in mailkit?

Comment: How would you do it if UniqueIds were ints or strings? Do it the same way with UniqueIds.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I had to use SearchAsync to get uniqueids.

I did not ask my last question correctly. I was actually asking what methods to use get unique ids before fetching records.

Comment: Ah, as you discovered, the Search methods return UIDs. Search (SearchQuery.All) will get you the full list.